# Get option from specific start position?

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I've a select like this:

```
<select class="foo">
    <option></option>
    <option>item1</option>
    <option>item2</option>
</select>
```

I need to get only the option that have text inside, so I need to skip the first option and get only `Item1` and `Item2`

what I did

```
var opts = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//select[@class='foo']//option");
```

this will return of course 3 options, how can I do this? Thanks.

Comment: you can do it by iterating through `opts` and checking if the current option has values or if it is null and simply skip it and the rest of them that have values add in some kind of collection or array. Also, there is a good html parser: http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex

Comment: @HarunĆerim I already use `Html Agility Pack`, I need to get only the option with text inside, I know that is possible iterating over it, but it's not what I asked. I tried to use the `.Skip(1)` provided by `Linq` but this will lost all the properties of `Html Agility Pack` framework..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working xpath:

```
"//select[@class='foo']//option[string-length( text()) > 0]"
```

Answer (score 1):

This XPath might work faster as there is no calculation needed:

```
"//select[@class='foo']//option[text()]"
```