# Is possible keep the properties type after using linq selection?

Tags: c#, linq, html-agility-pack

This question is partially related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47430495/get-option-from-specific-start-position). In particular I need to keep the property of the type `HtmlNodeCollection`, essentially I need to get only the option of a `select` that have a text, the select structure infact, looks like this:

```
<select class="foo">
    <option></option>
    <option>item1</option>
    <option>item2</option>
</select>
```

so I did this:

```
var grps = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//select[@id='group_id_selector']//option")
           .Where(c => c.InnerText != string.Empty);
```

this code working but I can't access to the property of each object 'cause now the `grps` collection is an `Enumerable`, instead I need a `HtmlNodeCollection`, I tried to add as `HtmlNodeCollection` to the end but the code return `null`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `ToList()` method is what you miss here, try this:

```
var grps = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//select[@id='group_id_selector']//option")
       .Where(c => c.InnerText != string.Empty).ToList();
```

`Where`, `Select` methods (and some more) return `Enumerable` objects. Calling `ToList()` method will return corresponding type :)

Comment: nice, this is the result of many hours of development haha, thanks :)